# Who enforces the rules that the gods must obey?

Tags: danmachi

In episode 10, we learn that gods are forbidden from entering the dungeon. This is apparently against the rules.

But who enforces the rules? What happens to someone found in defiance of them? I mean, Hestia and co. *are* gods, after all.

Comment: I don't have any resources to support this possibility, but maybe Zeus? Zeus is known as the god of gods in the Greek Mythology. And Hermes seems to talk about him as if Bell is his son.

Furthermore, the other possibility is that entering in the dungeon is dangerous for the gods themselves. As they may not be able to defend themselves against monsters.

Answer (score 5):

Based on episode 13 of the series, it seems like the dungeon itself enforces the rules. While having Hestia and Hermes in the search party didn't trigger any ill-effects on its own, Hestia's use of her godly powers within the dungeon resulted in a boss-level enemy along with multiple smaller mobs breaking into the sanctuary of level 18, and the characters' reactions suggested that this was the dungeon reacting to (and being upset at) the use of the power.